# Nginx's proxy_pass and path failing

Tags: nginx

So I have this Nginx configuration

```
location /todomvc {
  proxy_pass  http://s3bucket/testtarget/todomvc/;
}
```

Then I access it this way

```
http://localhost/todomvc
```

The index.html loads but the resources like javascript, css fails because of path issues.

An example entry in the index.html is like this

```
<script src="node_modules/todomvc-common/base.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/react/dist/react.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/react/dist/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
```

I opened up Chrome Dev tools to see why I'm getting 404s on the assets. I found out that it was requesting them like this

```
http://localhost/node_modules/todomvc-common/base.js
http://localhost/node_modules/react/dist/react.js
http://localhost/node_modules/react/dist/JSXTransformer.js
```

So I tried accessing it like this but was shocked, it still 404

```
http://localhost/todomvc/node_modules/todomvc-common/base.js
http://localhost/todomvc/node_modules/react/dist/react.js
http://localhost/todomvc/node_modules/react/dist/JSXTransformer.js
```

Comment: Make it `location /todomvc/` (with trailing slash)

Comment: Thanks Alexey. I'll try it once I reach work. I'll keep you posted.